# Spring Boot Webflux: RouterFunctions Add Query Parameters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am trying to figure out how to add query parameters to a route when using RouterFunctions. Here's what I have so far:

```
  @Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routes() {
    return
        RouterFunctions.route()
            .GET("/one/{one}", routeHandlerOne::handlerOne)
            .GET("/two", routeHandlerOne::handlerTwo)
        .build();
}
```

For route `two` I want add a query parameter, like `/two?three`. Any help would be most helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

There is a `queryParam()` method on the RequestPredicates class you can use.

```
RouterFunctions.route()
   .GET("/one", RequestPredicates.queryParam("test", t -> true), new CustomHanlder())
   .build();
```

There are two overloaded methods for `queryParam()`. One takes the exact value to compare against ([javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/RequestPredicates.html#queryParam-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)). The second (the one in the example above) takes a predicate and will delegate to the handler function if the predicate returns true ([javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/RequestPredicates.html#queryParam-java.lang.String-java.util.function.Predicate-)).

You can then access the query params through the `ServerRequest` object in your handler function ie.

```
serverRequest.queryParam("test")
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the query params optional?

Comment: remove RequestPredicates.queryParam from the router and it will always go in that handler whether the query param is there or not. Then in your handler when you call serverRequest.queryParam() you are returned an Optional. The optional will be empty if the param was not sent.

Comment: Cool! I appreciate your response!!

Comment: I want to add multiple (more than 1 or n) query parameters to a route when using RouterFunctions. It is done successfully as the below:    
           RouterFunctions.route()
               .GET("/", RequestPredicates.queryParam("id", t -> true), g::h)
               .GET("/", RequestPredicates.queryParam("name", t -> true), g::h)
           .build();  
api is giving 200 resp if either id or name is being passed. I want api should give 200 response when only both id and name are being passed. if any extra 
field apart from id and name is passed or any field(either id or name) is missing.

Comment: @PRAFULANAND Can you please raise this as a new question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple query parameters then you can do it this way

```
        .GET("/login", RequestPredicates.all()
                .and(queryParam("username", t -> true))
                .and(queryParam("password", t -> true)), handler::login)
```